# How could I download videos from youtube using php?

Tags: php, video, youtube, download

So, i would like to download youtube videos using a php script. I have googled a lot for now and there where more solutions but the one was using the `http://youtube.com/get_video?data url` but that is not possible now for a long time. I have found a greasemonkey script which works fine but i don't have a clue how could it work with php. 
I have read that i must do something with the info which gives me for example this link:

```
http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=g1SADcP5g1o
```

The question is what would be the best approach for this?

Comment: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4664-PHP-Get-the-video-download-URL-using-the-YouTube-API.html

Comment: That is too old because youtube has changed some things from the year 2008

Comment: Guess you better read the API docs, then.

Comment: Yes but the policie of youtube does not allow downloading videos so i will find nothing usable there as i have read while googling

Answer (score 0):

I would try to get some `curl` requests going on any of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=download%20youtube%20videos) resources and try to automate it that way.

Comment: yes i've thought about it but i wanna come to that how is this working in the background

Answer (score 0):

I have it written in C++, not PHP. But it's not very simple yet not very complicated either. **get_video_info output is URL encoded. Decode it** and look for the **stream_map** set of streams. You'll notice a pattern in it. That's your starting point. Contains resolutions and download locations plus extras.

I wouldn't paste the PHP code here even if I had it :) They tend to change it...